# Taking over a project

Tags: asp.net, .net, code-behind

I recently was handed a project that went bad. I only have access to the code live on the server.

Is there a way to grab all of the files from the server and have a working version on my local machine.

The .aspx files on the server do not seem to contain the .aspx.cs files that i am looking for.

Comment: i am afraid the only way you have is to use some kind of decompilers for .NET, it might help a bit in reversing from the dlls back to the source code used to build them. as far as for the solution and project files you should probably create them by hand and then add each decompiled file one by one looking at its namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the files on the server, you can copy all files (and other related things such as databases) and it should *run* as-is.

If you have none of the code however you won't be able to change much. .aspx files are compiled at runtime so you can change whatever is in them, but logic will not be as easy.

.NET code decompiles reasonably nicely if it hasn't been obfuscated so you might try that as a last resort. But seriously, just find whoever originally wrote it and extort them until they divulge the source code.